# HtmlUnit click() on div does not trigger JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java, htmlunit

I am trying to get all images particularly from this website: http://web.archive.org/web/20160110012916/http://habibemaia.com/ . I can get almost all by gathering all "src" tags and downloading from there, but there are problems with the main picture which is changed by javascript either with timing or on a click event. I set up my webclient like this:

```
webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(true);
webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(15000);
webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScriptStartingBefore(5000);
webClient.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());
webClient.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true);
```

After I got the div I try to use click like this:

```
HtmlPage newPage = div.click();
DomNodeList<DomElement> newImages = newPage.getElementsByTagName("img");
for (DomElement img : newImages) {
    if (img.hasAttribute("src")) {
        newImagesStrings.add(img.getAttribute("src"));
        System.out.println("Image added: "+img.getAttribute("src"));
    }
}
```

If I click on this div int the browser, a new image appears. Unfortunately this code does not trigger the javascript that changes the image. I have tried using

```
webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(3000);
```

after click(), as suggested elsewhere, but no luck. The page does not change. Now I am out of ideas completely. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(15000);
webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScriptStartingBefore(5000);
```

are both no option settings. The make only sense if you call them after some action - remove this from the setup part of your code.

Regarding the images: I did a quick analysis of the page with firebug. For me it looks like all the images are part of the code and the javascript only toggles the visibility (with some fancy effects).

Maybe something like:

- find the div with class 'cameraCont'
- iterate over all children with the style 'cameraSlide'
- every of this div has an img child that points to a different image

Comment: You are right,that solved it. And thanks for the other tips too!

Comment: Hmm, I can see the image links in Chrome debug, but when I do getPage(), only the first image is there, the other divs are empty.

Comment: Maybe because the other divs have display: none style on them? I'd like to get these divs with generally collecting all divs, not by class or id. I'm using 2.20 version that might be a problem?

Comment: 2.20 is really old. It is usually a good idea to use the latest snapshot builds (http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/gettingLatestCode.html). We do a lot of enhancements and bug fixes all the time and for the snapshots releases we have the same quality checks in place like for the real releases.

Comment: But how come when I use getPage() and waitForBackgroundJavascript(10000), the said divs are empty, but when I go to page and check in Chrome, they are filled with the src tags? Doesn't it have to do with HtmlUnit not getting divs with display: none?

Comment: HtmlUnit tries to mimic the (supported) browsers as close as possible. If you find some place where the behavior is different then this is a bug and you should report this bug. But keep in mind the developer team is not that big and we are doing the development in our spare time. This means you have to help us to nail down the bug see http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/submittingBugs.html and http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/submittingJSBugs.html for some hints.